# Lightweight Docker orchestrator for single server

Tags: docker

I am exploring using Docker for some components that are harder to package for the distro I'm using, or just outright more convenient to use that way.

I have explored [Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/) but since I'll be doing this on a single node I think it's overkill - I won't need much of the stuff that k8s provides and the resource consumption going to be too much.

I am not sure of what options I have to manage docker containers otherwise. I am interested mainly in:

- managing lifecycle
- gathering logs
- understanding of inter-container dependencies (e.g. start *db* container first and then the *app* container )

I looked at [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) but it's not meant for production environments.  I also found some articles about [running Docker containers using systemd](https://container-solutions.com/running-docker-containers-with-systemd/) but there seem to be a number of caveats there.

What options are there for lightweight docker container managmenent, especially for single nodes?

Answer (score 2):

There is [Dokku](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/), which aims to be a Platform as a Service (PaaS) similar to Heroku, but self-hosted.

> #### What is Dokku?
>
> Dokku is an extensible, open source Platform as a Service that runs on
>   a single server of your choice.

It features [deployments via `git push`](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/application-deployment/) and can manage dependencies (e.g. databases)

Logs are [also collected](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/logs/).

I have never used it myself, but it seems like a stable and actively maintained software that fits your requirements.

Comment: Looks interesting, thanks! I think this is a bit too much on top of Docker than I prefer, but I may have the chance to play with it later in the future.